# Symfony there are no commands defined in the "make" namespace

Tags: php, symfony, terminal, doctrine-odm

Following the documentation found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) I enter `php bin/console make:entity Product` in Terminal and get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
> There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.

Comment: did you require **doctrine** and **maker** ? **Installing Doctrine** step of the documentation you posted. Also you can see the full list of available commands by typing `php bin/console`

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html

Comment: `make:entity` is for ORM, not ODM. FWIW we still provide the "old" generator with ODM

Comment: @knets I did follow those installation instructions. Doctrine installed fine but running the `composer require doctrine maker` (as per the documentation) I get the following error `[UnexpectedValueException]                                                
  Could not parse version constraint maker: Invalid version string "maker"`

Comment: Only require one package at a time.  composer require doctrine followed by composer require maker

Comment: @Cerad When I run `composer require maker` I get the following error: `[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package maker. Did you mean one of these? yab/formmaker yab/crudmaker greabock/maker ctf0/simple-menu symfony/maker-bundle`
So I ran composer require symfony/maker-bundle and received this: `[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package symfony/maker-bundle at any version matching your PH P version 5.5.36.0`

Comment: S4 requres php 7.0 or better.  Go back to the docs you were following and select the correct version of symfony in the upper right hand corner.  You will ultimately end up using generate:entity not make:entity

Comment: @Cerad I'm running Symfony 3.1

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html

Answer (score 48):

### Maybe you were using the `prod` environment?

The [`website-skeleton`](https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton/blob/4.1/composer.json) puts the Maker Bundle in the `require-dev` section of your `composer.json` by default:

```
"require-dev": {
    ...
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    ...
}
```

If you've set `APP_ENV=prod` in your `.env` file and ran `bin/console` it would ignore all `dev` requirements and thus *wouldn't enable the Maker Bundle*.

Simply enabling the `dev` environment again (`APP_ENV=dev`) would do the trick then.

Comment: I had my env as `local` switched it back to `dev` and it did the trick

Answer (score 22):

`make` is a command of doctrine component. Just add doctrine maker.

```
composer require doctrine maker
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine

Comment: Nope.  You do need doctrine but the make:entity command is actually in the MakerBundle.

Comment: Fixed response with doc

Comment: Running `composer require doctrine maker` gives me the following error: `[UnexpectedValueException]                                                
  Could not parse version constraint maker: Invalid version string "maker"`

Comment: Are you using symfony4?

Comment: @sensorario No.  3.1

Comment: The documentation you pointed to in your question is related to Symfony4.

Comment: You need Symfony ^3.4|^4.0.

Comment: @sensorario it points to `current` which now at this time is 4 :)

Answer (score 14):

You need Symfony 3.4 or higher. For Symfony 3.4 you will need to add it to the registerBundles function in config/AppKernerl():

```
            if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            // [...]
            $bundles[] = new \Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle();
        }
```

Bear in mind that the environment where it is installed is 'dev'.

Comment: Exactly what i missed. I forgot that in symfony 3.4 we need to add it to bundles...
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

try

```
composer remove maker
composer require maker --dev
```

and then

```
php bin/console make:entity Product
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html

Comment: When I run `composer require maker --dev` I get the following error:
`[InvalidArgumentException]     
  Could not find package maker.  
  Did you mean one of these?     
      yab/formmaker              
      yab/crudmaker              
      greabock/maker             
      ctf0/simple-menu           
      symfony/maker-bundle`
So I ran `composer require symfony/maker-bundle` and received this:
`[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find package symfony/maker-bundle at any version matching your PH  
  P version 5.5.36.0`

Comment: see here
https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/maker-bundle

maker-bundle requires
php: ^7.0.8

Comment: this hosed all of my bundles.    Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AbstractAdapter::get(string $key, callable $callback,
   ?float $beta = NULL) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface::get(string $key, callable $ca
  llback, ?float $beta = NULL, ?array &$metadata = NULL)

Answer (score 6):

You must define the "dev" env in the command line :

```
php bin/console --env dev
php bin/console make:entity Product --env dev
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem just happend to me.
I was in test environment.
You have to be in dev environment.

Check APP_ENV value in .env file. It must be the following :

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

Comment: Well that is ridiculous - I need to create a migration for a test environment database, which is targeted only when `APP_ENV=test`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are in prod environment. Check if your the value of APP_ENV inside .env file is not equals to prod.

In case you generate a .env.local file, you have to delete it in your dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use composer for installer maker bundle, you have install a light version of symfony.

> **composer require symfony/maker-bundle**

but if you have this problem surely need composer doctrine and security

> **composer require doctrine/orm**

with

> **require doctrine/doctrine-bundle**

And

> **composer require symfony/security-bundle**
>
> **composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle**

Now you have this with **php bin/console** !

> make   make:auth                   Creates a Guard authenticator of
> different flavors
>
> make:command                Creates a new console command class
>
> make:controller             Creates a new controller class
>
> make:crud                   Creates CRUD for Doctrine entity class
> make:docker:database        Adds a database container to your
> docker-compose.yaml file
>
> make:entity                 Creates or updates a Doctrine entity
> class, and optionally an API Platform resource
>
> make:fixtures               Creates a new class to load Doctrine
> fixtures
>
> make:form                   Creates a new form class
>
> make:message                Creates a new message and handler
>
> make:messenger-middleware   Creates a new messenger middleware
>
> make:migration              Creates a new migration based on
> database changes
>
> make:registration-form      Creates a new registration form system
>
> make:reset-password         Create controller, entity, and
> repositories for use  with symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle
> make:serializer:encoder     Creates a new serializer encoder class
>
> make:serializer:normalizer  Creates a new serializer normalizer
> class
>
> make:stimulus-controller    Creates a new Stimulus controller
>
> make:subscriber             Creates a new event subscriber class
>
> make:test                   [make:unit-test|make:functional-test]
> Creates a new  test class
>
> make:twig-extension         Creates a new Twig extension class
>
> make:user                   Creates a new security user class
>
> make:validator              Creates a new validator and constraint
> class
>
> make:voter                  Creates a new security voter class

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed symfony / maker-bundle for the dev mode you will only be able to use it for this mode. If you are in
 prod mode then go to dev mode and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev` it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem you just create new project with (full properties), here is command for create a project:

symfony new --full project-name

after you create project like the command above, you now can able to use (make).